form still submitting even though input is incorrect react
I have a contact form I have created with validation and it mostly works. However it still gets submitted even if the information is wrong. Here is my code:
//ContactForm.jsx:

const ContactForm = () => {
  // react states for required field inputs
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [subject, setSubject] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  // react state for confirmation of message sent
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(true);

  // To set focus on each input field and return error when field is not properly filled
  const [ focused, setFocused ] = React.useState({});

  const handleBlur = (e) => {
    setFocused(prev => ({...prev, [e.target.name]: true}))
  }

  // For focusing the input field for correct information
  const isFocused = (name) => {
    return focused[name] === true
  }

  // the handle submit function combined with EmailJs
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const serviceId = '';
    const templateId = '';
    const publicKey = '';

    // To create an object that contains template parameter
    const templateParams = {
      from_name: name,
      from_email: email,
      from_subject: subject,
      to_name: 'Lucy',
      message: message,
    }

    // sends email using emailjs, passing params 
    emailjs.send(serviceId, templateId, templateParams, publicKey)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Email sent successfully', response);
        setName('');
        setEmail('');
        setSubject('');
        setMessage('');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error sending email:', error)
      })

      // Displays confirmation once form is submitted
      setShow(false);
  }

return (
    <>
      {show ? (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='form'>
          <div className='textbox name'>
            <input
              name='from_name'
              value={name}
              type='text'
              placeholder='Your Name'
              pattern='^[A-Za-z]{2,16}$'
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
              data-focused={isFocused('from_name').toString()}
              required
            />
            <span>Please fill in this field</span>
          </div>
          <div className='textbox email'>
            <input
              name='from_email'
              value={email}
              type='email'
              placeholder='Your Email'
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              data-focused={isFocused('from_email').toString()}
              required
            />
            <span>Please fill in this field</span>
          </div>
          <div className='textbox subject'>
            <select
              name='from_subject'
              value={subject}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onChange={(e) => setSubject(e.target.value)}
              data-focused={isFocused('from_subject').toString()}
              required
            >
              <option value=''>What is your enquiry about?</option>
              <option value='General'>General</option>
              <option value='Review'>Review</option>
              <option value='Business'>Business</option>
              <option value='Other'>Other</option>
            </select>
            <span>Please select an appropiate subject</span>
          </div>
          <div className='textbox message'>
            <textarea
              name='message'
              value={message}
              cols="30"
              rows="15"
              minLength={100}
              placeholder='What is your message to us about? Any specifics, please add here.'
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
              data-focused={isFocused('message').toString()}
              required
            />
            <span>Message needs to be at least 100 characters long</span>
          </div>
          <div >
            <button 
              disabled={!name | !email | !subject | !message }
              className='message-submit-btn'
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              type='button'
              onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
            >
              SUBMIT MESSAGE
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
        ) : (
        <div className='sent-confirm'>
          <CircleCheckBig 
            style={{color: 'var(--btn-green)'}}
            strokeWidth={0.4} 
            size={400}/>
          <p className='sent-confirm-text'>Message Sent!</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default ContactForm

ContactUs.css. This css code is used to display the error if occurs:
/* validation code */
.form input:invalid[data-focused='true'] {
  border-color: red;
}

.form input:invalid[data-focused='true'] ~ span {
  color: red;
  display: block;
}

.form select:invalid[data-focused='true'] {
  border-color: red;
}

.form select:invalid[data-focused='true'] ~ span {
  color: red;
  display: block;
}

.form textarea:invalid[data-focused='true'] {
  border-color: red;
}

.form textarea:invalid[data-focused='true'] ~ span {
  color: red;
  display: block;
}

...

/* submit button */
.message-submit-btn {
  background: var(--btn-green);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-size: 0.88rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.message-submit-btn:disabled {
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: scale(1) !important;
}

What is it that I am doing wrong? Any suggestions would very much be appreciated, thank you.

Can you be clearer on the wrong information that gets submitted? Are there specific validations that should be met before the form can be submitted? Currently, your form does not get submitted until something is typed into the form field so I'm not entirely sure what the challenge is.

For e.g. name input needs to have at least two letters, email input needs to valid and message textarea needs to have at least 100 characters etc. Once these inputs are filled correctly, then the submit button should appear enable but it enables anyway as soon as text is put all of the boxes. I have fixed the actual submitting problem though thanks to what @David suggested below.

If you want to achieve these stipulated conditions for the form, then you will need to write a custom validation logic that handles these conditions. You can check the length of each input value and on the basis of that, disable or enable your submit button.


it still submits even when the information is wrong

Technically no it doesn't.  What does happen is the handleSubmit function is called.  But it's not being called by the form submitting.  It's being called by clicking the button:
onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}

Validation doesn't prevent the user from clicking a button.
The form is already calling handleSubmit when it's submitted:
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='form'>

There's no need to call it twice.  Just remove that onClick handler from the button.  (And remove type="button" so the button will submit the form.)

Thank you, i did what you suggested and it is working. Just one thing, I want the button to only enable once the input boxes are filled correctly because at the moment, it just enables as soon as text is put into all of them.

@ryanl your disabled logic currently checks whether the states(name, email etc.) contain truthy values(values that map to true). For your desired functionality, you will have to write custom logic to verify whether they are valid. You must also ensure the user is informed why the button is disabled.
